# Define all my Enumerations in one file Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I would like to create a file to define all my **Enumerations** and use them later in models or migrations.

That because I have the same enumeration in many models and i don't want to redefine them each time.

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special package for it. It's very simple to use.
https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum

Create a folder, typically is `App/Enums`, then create a Class(es) decoupled by category or as you need.

```
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

final class UserType extends Enum
{
    //Here define your constants
    const Administrator = 0;
    const Moderator = 1;
    const Subscriber = 2;
    const SuperAdministrator = 3;
}
```

Then, you can simple "use" this Class whatever in project and access the values as easy as :

```
use App\Enums\UserType;
...

class SomeClass {
...
public function test() {
        return UserType::Moderator; // Returns 1
    }
}
```